# Is it unethical to get job offers I don't want to increase my worth for the jobs I want?

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, negotiation

I learned in negotiation theory that one must always have other offers, in order for companies to value the person more and extend the most competitive offers that they possibly can.

But, is such action unethical?  Should I interview and obtain offers from companies that I do not truly have any plans to work for?  Or, is it just simply "being smart about it", and that it is really a necessary strategy when job searching?

Comment: "I learned in negotiation theory" - they do classes in that?

Comment: If just applying for X number of jobs granted you Y number of offers, you're either an amazing rockstar and can negotiate without those other offers or you're in an undersaturated market in which case, again, you can negotiate without those offers. What leads you to believe it is so easy to get competing offers?

Comment: Related: [Practicing interviews by attending interviews for jobs I probably will not accept (duplicate)](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/67031/practicing-interviews-by-attending-interviews-for-jobs-i-probably-will-not-accep)

Answer (score 4):

> I learned in negotiation theory that one must always have other offers, in order for companies to value the person more and extend the most competitive offers that they possibly can.

Actually - it's more important that you have options so that you are negotiating from a strong position. If you don't have a plan B, then you are going to have a lower personal bar of acceptance in negotiations.

> But, is such action unethical? Should I interview and obtain offers from companies that I do not truly have any plans to work for? Or, is it just simply "being smart about it", and that it is really a necessary strategy when job searching?

This is not really smart:

If you have a better offer from company B, why bother negotiating with company A - you have the better offer already.

If you plan on playing A and B off of each other, this will likely backfire after the first or second time you raise the stakes on either company and they decide to go with someone less demanding.

The best strategy is to know your value and simply state that - don't refer to "other offers".

Comment: To simply go looking for offers you never intend to even consider will only result in you burning bridges.